# ignoring newline character in regex match

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to replace all matching occurrences with title cases using the following script. When there is a newline character between filter words (in this case 'ABC' and 'DEF') that line doesn't get replaced as intended.

How can I ignore the newline character in this case?

Edit: I don't want to strip all newline characters entirely from the string, but only strip those between the filter words.

Edit2: I edited the text and script to better reflect on the issue I am experiencing. If I include `flags=re.DOTALL` argument, it will give me:

```
  mmm    = "Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello
              Hello Hello Hello Hello",
  Bbb   = "Bbb",
```

whereas the output I want is (notice that `bbb` is not capitalized):

```
  mmm    = "Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello
              Hello Hello Hello Hello",
  bbb   = "bbb",
```

The following is the script I am using.

```
test_string = '''
  mmm    = "hello hello hello hello hello hello
              hello hello hello hello",
  bbb   = "bbb",
'''

rex = r'(?<= mmm)(.*)(?=\")'

def maketitle(match_obj):
    return match_obj.group(0).title()

formatted = re.sub(rex, maketitle, test_string, flags=re.DOTALL)

print(formatted)
```

Comment: Please create a [mcve] working on several examples.

Comment: `re.sub` typically will replace everything if it can.  So we need to see your code, to understand what might be going wrong.

Comment: Found out that the newline character is causing the problem, so updated the question accordingly

Comment: I thought if DOTALL is not set, then newlines are ignored by default?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following code gives the result you expect:

```
test_string = '''
  mmm    = "hello hello hello hello hello hello
              hello hello hello hello",
  bbb   = "bbb",
'''

rex = r'(?<= mmm)\s*=\s*"[^"]*'

def maketitle(match_obj):
    return match_obj.group(0).title()

formatted = re.sub(rex, maketitle, test_string)

print(formatted)
```

I'm assuming that the value you want to "title-case" is always between double quotes, and that it can not contain a double-quote (escaped in some way). Handling escaping would be possible with a slightly more complex regex, though.

Answer (score 20):

Use the `re.DOTALL` flag:

```
formatted = re.sub(rex, maketitle, string, flags=re.DOTALL)
print(formatted)
```

According to the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.DOTALL):

> `re.DOTALL`
>   Make the '.' special character match any character at all, including a newline; without this flag, '.' will match anything except a newline.

Comment: thanks for your comment, but including the arg will capitalize following words as well. Please refer to the updated example.