# Use CR/LF pair to reject a match using Regex

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I am struggling to reject matches for words separated by newline character.

Here's the test string:

```
Cardoza Fred
Catto, Philipa
Duncan, Jean
Jerry Smith
and
but
and
Andrew

Red 
Abcd

DDDD
```

**Rules for regex:**

1) Reject a word if it's followed by comma. Therefore, we will drop Catto.

2) Only select words that begin with a capital letter. Hence, `and` etc. will be dropped

3) If the word is followed by a carriage return (i.e. it is the first name, then ignore it).

Here's my attempt: `\b([A-Z][a-z]+)\s(?!\n)`

**Explanation:**

```
\b                #start at a word boundary
([A-Z][a-z]+)     #start with A-Z followed by a-z
\s                #Last name must be followed by a space character
(?!\n)            #The word shouldn't be followed by newline char i.e. ignore first names.
```

There are two problems with my regex.

**1)** `Andrew` is matched as `Andre`. I am unsure why `w` is missed. I have also observed that `w` of `Andrew` is not missed if I change the bottom portion of the sample text to remove all characters including and after `w` of Andrew. i.e. sample text would look like:

```
Cardoza Fred
Catto, Philipa
Duncan, Jean
Jerry Smith
and
but
and
Andrew
```

The output should be:

```
Cardoza 
Jerry
```

**You might ask:** Why should `Andrew` be rejected? This is because of two reasons: a) `Andrew` is not followed by space. b) There is no `first_name "space" last_name` combination.

**2)** The first names are getting selected using my regex. How do I ignore first names?

I researched SO. It seems there is similar thread [ignoring newline character in regex match](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52197413/ignoring-newline-character-in-regex-match), but the answer doesn't talk about ignoring `\r`.

This problem is adapted from Watt's Begining Regex book. I have spent close to 1 hour on this problem without any success. Any explanation will be greatly appreciated. I am using python's `re` module.

Here's [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/kqeMcH/1) for reference.

Comment: Try `(?m)\w+(?!\r?$|[\w,])`. See live demo here https://regex101.com/r/E0LBg5/1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Andre` (and not the trailing `w`) is being matched in your regex because the last token is negative lookahead for `\n`, and just before that is an *optional* space. So, `Andrew<end of line>` fails due to being at the end of the line, so the engine backtracks to `Andre`, which succeeds.

Maybe the optional quantifier in `\s?` in your regex101 was a typo, but it would probably be easier to start from scratch. If you want to find the initial names that are followed by a space and then another name, then you can use

```
^[A-Z][a-z]+(?= [A-Z][a-z]+$)
```

with the `m` flag:

https://regex101.com/r/kqeMcH/5

The `m` flag allows for `^` to match the beginning of a line, and `$` to match the end of the line - easier than messing with looking for `\n`s. (Without the `m` flag, `^` will only match the beginning of the *string*, while `$` will similarly only match the end of the *string*)

That is, start with repeated alphabetical characters, then lookahead for a space and more alphabetical characters, followed by the end of the line. Using positive lookahead will be a lot easier than negative lookahead for newlines and such.

Note that *literal spaces* are a bit more reliable in a regex than `\s`, because `\s` matches *any* whitespace character, including newlines. If you're looking for literal spaces, better to use a literal space.

To use flags in Python regex, either use the `flags=`, or define the flags at the beginning of the pattern, eg

```
pattern = r'(?m)^[a-z]+(?= [A-Z][a-z]+$)'
```

Comment: Thanks CertainPerformance. Unfortunately, the output isn't matching with your regex101. The output should be `Cardoza` `Jerry`. Also, are `gmi` flags supported by `re` of Python? I am not sure so I thought of asking you.

Comment: Check the regex101 again, it looks to indeed be matching: `Full match 0-7 Cardoza` `Full match 41-46 Jerry`